# How to Change App title to Logo in Android Studio

Tags: android

How to change the App Title to a Logo? seems this code is not working to Remove the App Title still in there when i build the app.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you can use custom toolbar for that purpose in your layout.xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >


      <Imageview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now set the title and logo  of your toolbar like this in your activity.java file in onCreate() method:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
Imageview mTitle = (Imageview) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

Don't forget to add this theme in style.xml to your activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Or you can try this if you don't want to use custom toolbar:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);  // showing the icon to your action bar 
actionBar.setTitle("");//set title to your action bar
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, but where should i put them? seems got a lot of errors when i put the <android.support....../> on the AndroidManefest.xml, so sorry im new to android im still learning

Comment: also the Toolbar toolbarTop...... code when i put the code the ImageView turns to red and when i put the import android.widget.ImageView; nothings happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Actionbar then just do as following if you want to do it with java code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Or on the Manifest xml :

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
   android:icon="@drawable/your_icon" 
   android:label="" />
```

on your activity.

and if you want to enable back on clicking your logo then use:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

At styles.xml first make a style for action bar with no title and with the logo like that

```
<style name="ActionBar.NoTitle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    </style>
```

Then create custome theme for your activity with new actionbar style

```
<!-- Create a style for MainActivity called AppTheme.Main that uses our custom ActionBar style -->

<style name="AppTheme.Main" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.NoTitle</item>
</style>
```

Then go to manifest file under the specified activity set theme to AppTheme.Main

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Main"
```

I wish that help everyone